# PDFCreator in VBA option for not opening PDF automatically

Tags: vba, pdf, merge, acrobat

I have a problem with PDFCreator where i am doing a series of printjobs in VBA, but i want to do it silent. the problem is that for every pdf the PDFCreator makes it automatically opens acrobat reader, and the application hangs until you close it manually, which isn't really that smart. What can i do?

This is the settings for the pdfjob

```
'Assign settings for PDF job
With pdfjob
.cOption("UseAutosave") = 1
.cOption("UseAutosaveDirectory") = 1
.cOption("AutosaveDirectory") = sPDFPath
.cOption("AutosaveFilename") = sPDFName
.cOption("AutosaveFormat") = 0 ' 0 = PDF
DefaultPrinter = .cDefaultPrinter
.cDefaultPrinter = "PDFCreator"
.cClearCache
End With
```

Comment: Which Office version do you have? If you have greater than 2003 version then creating pdf is inbuilt in MS Office which can silently print

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
.cOption("OpenOutputFile")=0
.cOption("RunProgramAfterSaving")=0
.cOption("RunProgramBeforeSaving")=0
.cOption("SendEmailAfterAutoSaving")=0
.cOption("AutosaveStartStandardProgram")=0
```

Note: although Office 2007+ supports saving/exporting to PDF (when you install an additional official Add-On), the options are very very limited. With PDFCreator you can control much more options and it produces extremely smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I used PDF creator, but looking at my files, I find I have a .cStart option.

```
With PDFCreator1
    .cStart "/NoProcessingAtStartup"
    .cOption("UseAutosave") = 1
    .cOption("UseAutosaveDirectory") = 1
    .cOption("AutosaveDirectory") = strSaveDirectory
    .cOption("AutosaveFilename") = strFileName
    .cOption("AutosaveFormat") = 0 ' 0 = PDF
    DefaultPrinter = .cDefaultPrinter
    .cDefaultPrinter = "PDFCreator"
    .cClearCache
End With
```